# Where to start generating buttons on WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF form with Grid and inside that Grid in Row(1).Column(1) i have StackPanel.
Inside that StackPanel i want to generate buttons.

I don't know how many buttons will be generated, since form(with grid and stackPanel) can be of different size.

Code below works, buttons are getting generated if i run that piece of code on Button_Click for example.

But buttons are not generated if I run this piece of code after InitializeComponent().

I guess, that after InitializeComponent WPF form is still not drawn(or finished loading) so my stPanel.ActualHeigh =="0", and since I can't divide with zero nothing acctualy happens.

Can you suggest some workaround, or even better proper solution?

```
       public partial class frmReceipt : Window
    {
        public frmReceipt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            addButtonGrp(); //am i too fast :)
        }


        private void addButtonGrp()
        {

            //Calculate size of container to determine numbers of button
            int btnMinimumHeightSize = 30;

            int btnNumberCreated = (Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualHeight) / btnMinimumHeightSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < btnNumberCreated; i++)
            {

                CreateGroupButtons btn = new CreateGroupButtons();
                var btnX = new Button();

                btnX = (btn.addButton(i, btnMinimumHeightSize, Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth)));
                btnX.Click += ClickHandlerGrp;

                if (i == btnNumberCreated - 1)
                {
                    btnX.Height = btnMinimumHeightSize + ((Convert.ToDouble(stPanel.ActualHeight) / btnMinimumHeightSize) % 1) * (btnNumberCreated);
                }

                stPanel.Children.Add(btnX);
            }
        }



        private void ClickHandlerGrp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked button number: " + button.Tag);

            string test = Convert.ToString(button.Tag);

            switch (test)
            {
                case "PLUGrp":
                    addButtonGrp(); //this is just for test, i don't want to generate buttons this way
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ActualWidth/ ActualHeight are 0 before window is loaded. that is why code works in Button_Click handler, but not in constructor. give a try to ItemsControl for your task

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will definitely research ItemsControl.

Comment: Do not create UI elements in code behind. Use an ItemsControl with the Button defined in its ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens So in XAML i create <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate>
<Button >. Then i just say create n buttons, and then with code behind fill the size, button position, color, content? What is advantage of ItemTemplate if only thing I know is that I need  buttons(everything else about buttons will change( even the number of them). If I understand correctly, what I am doing here is XAML anti-pattern right? But since I don't know any property of button I wonder if ItemsControl is right approach? English is not my native language so I hope that you understand what i am trying to say :)

Comment: You would bind the Button's properties (like Content etc). to properties of the item class, i.e. the element type of the collection that the ItemsControl's ItemsSource is bound to. Start read here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right about running your code before the form has displayed. (It would be easy to check by putting a breakpoint on the for loop)

You can use the Loaded event of the form. Put this in your XAML for the window

```
Loaded="MainWindowView_OnLoaded"
```

and this in your C#

```
    private void MainWindowView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addButtonGrp();
    }
```

This should then fire after the form is displayed, when you know the height of your stack panel.

Comment: That's a relief - after I posted it I was worried that the stack panel would also be zero height because it was empty, and you might have to get the height from somewhere else.